# getByteTimeDomainData while audio is paused?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I'm working with the first example on [Visualizations with Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API).

My goal is to use a slider to see the waveform at different times without playing the audio.

However, it seems that the  audio must be playing in order for `analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray)` to get the data at the current time. I set the `audioElement.currentTime`, but while paused, `analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray)` just returns [128, 128, ..., 128].

I'd just like to get the data for a specific time while the audio is paused. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

`getByteTimeDomainData` is used for real-time audio analysis, in order to generate waveform without playing you need to decode the entire audio file using audio context method `decodeAudioData` and get audio data (Float32Array) from the decoded audio buffer using the `getChannelData` method which you would process to get probably average sample value for each canvas pixel and render it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the audio context must be running for the data to change in an `AnalyserNode`.   I can't think of any other way with WebAudio.